# can we add twitter count button on wordpress?

Tags: twitter

i have seen many post regarding adding twitter's tweet button on wordpress page using different plugins.

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"
      data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
      data-via="wpbeginner"
      data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>"
      data-related="syedbalkhi:Founder of WPBeginner"
      data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
```

i want to ask that it is possible when someone click on

Tweet

button on wordpress site then after that tweet button should display number of tweets(every time increase the counter when someone clicks it)

Comment: This is absolutely possible, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775578/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-twitter-share-count-for-a-specific-url) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible anymore (as of Nov 20, 2015) as Twitter's share count API has been deprecated. https://twittercommunity.com/t/a-new-design-for-tweet-and-follow-buttons/52791